# Can I unwrap std::map iterator to structured binding of optionals?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, structured-bindings

Consider following code:

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

const std::map<int, std::string> numberToStr{{1, "one"}, {2,"two"}};
int main() {
    auto it = numberToStr.find(2);
    if (it ==numberToStr.end()){
        return 1;
    }
    const auto&[_, str] = *it;
    std::cout << str;
}
```

Is there any way for me to do the unwrapping of potentially dereferenced `it` to 2 optionals(_ and str) so I can then write:

```
const auto&[_, str] = // some magic;
// _ is std::optional<int>, str is std::optional<str>
if (!str){
    return 1;
}
std::cout << *str;
}
```

I presume not since structured bindings are language level thing, and std::optional is a library feature and afaik there is no way to customize the interaction.

Note: I presume I could implement my own map that returns iterators that know if they point to .end(), and "hack" customization points to do optional logic based on that, I am asking for general use case when I do not control the container.

Comment: I don't follow. If you don't control the container, you get what you get. What sort of *magic* are you expecting? Is it fine if the call to `.find` is wrapped in a function that returns a pair of optionals?

Comment: @cigien I hit a wall, if I knew a some direction to solution I would provide it, but I only know what I want(unpacking maybe pair that .find returns into pair of optional-s), Nathan answer is I think best I can get without WG21 baking stuff like this into language...

Comment: Sure, that's fine. Your wording threw me off a bit that's all. BTW this would not be a language issue anyway, but a library issue, since it deals with what `map::find` returns. So it would be up to LWG, I think. Not that the signature is ever going to be changed to do what you want.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me. The code is already checking the result of `find()` to make sure the returned `iterator` is valid, in which case the `string` for that map element is also valid and can't be optional. There is no need to use a structured binding at all when you can just access the `string` directly from the iterator, eg: `if (it == numberToStr.end()){ return 1; } std::cout << it->second;`

Comment: @cigien: LWG is one of many parts of WG21, along with language-focused groups like CWG.

Comment: @DavisHerring Oh, thanks I didn't realize that, it makes complete sense. That was silly of me :(

Comment: @cigien: No problem: there’s a [website](https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee) to tell you these things, but you have to know it exists!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a helper function like

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename... Rest>
std::pair<std::optional<Key>, std::optional<Value>> my_find(const std::map<Key, Value, Rest...>& map, const Key& to_find)
{
    auto it = map.find(to_find);
    if (it == map.end())
        return {};
    else
        return {it->first, it->second};
}
```

and then you would use it like

```
const auto&[_, str] = my_find(numberToStr, 2);
// _ is std::optional<int>, str is std::optional<str>
if (!str){
    return 1;
}
std::cout << *str;
```

---

If you only care about the value, you can shorten the code a bit by just returning it instead with

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename... Rest>
std::optional<Value> my_find(const std::map<Key, Value, Rest...>& map, const Key& to_find)
{
    auto it = map.find(to_find);
    if (it == map.end())
        return {};
    else
        return {it->second};
}
```

and then you'd use it like

```
auto str = my_find(numberToStr, 2);
// str is std::optional<str>
if (!str){
    return 1;
}
std::cout << *str;
```

Comment: Yup, probably what the OP wants, nice answer :) I shouldn't have waited for confirmation on the comment :(

Comment: This is what OP asked for, but I think they'd be better served by `std::optional<Value> my_at(const std::map<Key, Value, Rest...>& map, const Key& to_find)`

Comment: @Caleth good point.  added that into the answer.

Comment: What's the point of wrapping `find` like this anyway?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Honestly, IDK.  It's what the OP asked for though.  There is going to be an if statement needed in the OP's call site regardless of which method is used so it's not really saving anything.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili it saves me from obnoxious !=.end() , I personally *find* optional much nicer to use.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl You still have a check, you can't get a reference anymore, only a copy, everyone will wonder what `my_find` is/does. You're better off returning a pointer, which is null if the value isn't in the map. Then the check will be simpler and you'll get a reference. I'd still stick to the regular `find` since it's recognizable by everyone else too.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili maybe also it enables onelining this, I think my original code can not do that... since I must first check if it!=end before dereferencing it...  https://godbolt.org/z/7z6ron

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl how about [this](https://godbolt.org/z/9rdcf3) or [this](https://godbolt.org/z/jbez86).

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili both work, but I do not like raw pointers, or -> This is personal preference I understand that some people prefer your solution, for example they are much faster since there are no copies performed and code in solution can not be fixed since std::optional does not work for references.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl `optional<reference_wrapper<T>>` is a lengthy way of spelling `T*`

Answer (score 5):

The more C++20-idiomatic route would be to model the iterator as a possibly-empty range:

```
auto const rng = std::apply(
    [](auto it, auto end) { return std::ranges::subrange(it, end); },
    numberToStr.equal_range(2));
if (rng.empty())
    return 1;
auto const& [_, str] = *rng.begin();
std::cout << str;
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/eKojaG).

You can do this before C++20 using Boost.Ranges, which has a rather more ergonomic `iterator_range`:

```
auto const rng = boost::make_iterator_range(numberToStr.equal_range(2));
// ditto
```

Comment: Could you please explain why checking an empty range is better/more idiomatic than checking whether an iterator points to the end? Isn't that kinda what an empty range would be?

Comment: @Cedric it allows writing clearly-correct code using a `for` loop to guard access into the (possibly-empty) range. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1255r6.html

Comment: @Cedric to me range stuff is less idiomatic, but maybe it is just a thing of getting used to it, I remember I disliked boost::optional when I saw it for the first time...

Answer (score 4):

The desired API makes little sense to me. Why would you get back *two* optionals? The key is either in the map or not, that's a single dimension of optionality - it's not like you can get back an engaged key but a disengaged value or a disengaged key but an engaged value.

The API *should* be:

```cpp
template <typename Map, typename Key>
auto try_find(Map&, Key&&) -> optional<range_reference_t<Map>>;
```

But we can't actually write that using `std::optional`, because that one doesn't support optional references. Returning an actual `optional<value_type>` is both wasteful (extra copies) and likely semantically invalid (you probably wanted *that specific* value, not just *a* value).

So the first step is acquiring a better implementation of `optional` and using that. At which point, the implementation here is very easy:

```cpp
template <typename Map, typename Key>
auto try_find(Map& m, Key&& k) -> optional<range_reference_t<Map>>
{
    auto it = m.find(std::forward<Key>(k));
    if (it != m.end()) {
        return *it;
    } else {
        return nullopt;
    }
}
```

A different approach, which does work with `std::optional`, is to return an optional *iterator* instead of an optional reference. This has the benefit of being just as composable as `optional` while still working entirely within the standard library.

---

A third approach is to instead return a range:

```cpp
template <typename Map, typename Key>
auto try_find(Map& m, Key const& k) -> subrange<iterator_t<Map>>
{
    auto [f, l] = m.equal_range(key);
    return subrange(f, l);
}
```

This continues to be composable with all the ranges things. You just check for emptiness instead of engaged-ness:

```cpp
auto r = try_find(m, key);
if (r.empty()) {
    // nope
} else {
    // use r.front()
}
```

Comment: Well it is personal preference, I prefer that I can check just str and use it immediately, without need to first check the pair is fine, and then get .second from it. I had a long discussion on other A comments, this is my personal preference, hard to force somebody to agree. :) Same with optional of iterator, I do not like  ** (or equivalent) syntax. Still upvoted the answer since I had no idea  aboutoptional<range_reference_t<Map>>

Comment: `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<ValueType>>` is also an option (sic).

Comment: @ecatmur But that's not what you want to do, it's just a hack around a library deficiency. `range_reference_t<M>` need not have been an actual reference type, maybe I have a map that yields proxies - I'd want to preserve that. The other issue is it's not `optional<reference_wrapper<range_value_t<M>>` - it's more like `optional<reference_wrapper<remove_reference_t<range_reference_t<M>>>>`. But then that is valid even if we have proxies, and we're returning dangling references unconditionally. It's kind of a mess.

Comment: Well, that's `optional<conditional_t<is_reference_v<range_reference_t<M>>, reference_wrapper<remove_reference_t<range_reference_t<M>>>, range_reference_t<M>>>` then. It's a shame that we have `unwrap_reference` but not the reverse operation.